# Laravel / Vue.js. Looking for a Picture Editor to resize/crop before saving

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Using Vue.js and FileReader. I would like to resize and Crop my uploaded pictures before save using an Editor.

Any ideas how to integrate your recommanded Editor ?

I use this code in Vue.Js to load my file :

```
    imageChanged(e){
     var size = e.target.files[0].size;
       if(size < 1108659){
        console.log(e.target.files[0])
     var fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
        fileReader.onload=(e)=>{
        this.image=e.target.result
           }}
        },
```

Thank you

Comment: There is a plugin that will do the resizing of picture in the server side, and this is the `Intervention Image`. Read more at http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: Okay! Nice, Keep coding.

Comment: check `Croppie` it's my favorite plugin to do resizing in the client side & it's very easy to use check here https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/